# Как передать можно получит доступ к UI из класса который не наследует от Activity?

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с `MainActivity` котрое имеет доступ к UI , я реализовываю в нем возможность определения необходимых мне данных, которые как только подсчитываются устанавливаются в `TextView`. Проблема в том, что эти методы занимают много места и я создал класс `Helper` в который перенес все эти методы, но теперь я не могу получить доступ через `findViewById()` и даже если я передам TextView в конструкторе то я все равно не могу в него сделать `set()` так как пишет что `set()` может делать только активити которое его создало... Как красиво решить эту проблему не передавая ресурсы через конструктор и не используя `runOnUiThread()`

Answer (score 4):

Если вы имеете в виду, что у вас есть метод `set` в классе активити, коий вы хотите вызвать из метода другого класса, то можно передать в метод `Context`, скастовать его к типу активити и вызвать `set`

```
public void somMethodInSomeClazz(Context ctx, ...)
{
    ActivityMain act = (ActivityMain) ctx;
    act.set();
}
```

Тот же `Context` вы можете получить и из `TextView` методом `getContext()` и последующим кастованием

```
ActivityMain act = (ActivityMain) textView.getContext();
```

Comment: а можете сделать короткий пример? Допустим у нас 1 TextView и 2 класса (Main и Helper) и по условию я должен работать с TextView из Helper(а он не  имеет доступ к UI). А то я чет не до конца понял идею... В каком классе я должен определить мой TextView и куда передать Context.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, сделать можно слишком большим кол-вом способов. Задача и увас сформулирована очень размыто. Чем вам не нравится идея передать `TextView` в ваш класс?.. Из него можно и контекст, и активити получить и всё что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

А  просто создать локальную или глобальную переменную типа Helper и вызвать у нее соответствующие методы перед установкой значения TextView, не вариант?